# how to change the password in membership with oldpassword checking

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I developed a web application. It has a login form using ASP.NET membership. Now I need to add a form allowing to change the password. Before a new password can be set, the old password must be entered by the user.

How can I check if the old password is valid?

Comment: Hi ,Need to change only single password

Comment: Because need to change password based on the old password

Comment: What `PasswordFormat` does your MembershipProvider has been configured for? If it's `Hashed` you cannot check the old password because [SHA1](http://www.tech-faq.com/sha-1.html) is a one-way hash function. The membership provider simply will throw an exception if you try to call `GetPassword()` even if you have configured `enablePasswordRetrieval=true` in web.config what is another precondition.

Comment: yes i want add change password feature to my site.

Comment: I re-wrote the original question - I think it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

```
// checking if the old password is correct
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, oldPassword))  
{  
    // setting a new password
    string newPassword = MembershipUser.ResetPassword();  
}
```

[Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx)
[Membership.ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if The User logged In then you have the User Id

so retrieve all user Information like user name password using It.

now you Can just ask User to enter his old password now match this two if both matched then change the password with new One.

Comment: hi thank you for giving response how can i get oldpassword from membership please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ChangePassword control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.aspx